# Trouble with $.getJSON - looks like arrays inside of arrays

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, getjson

Ok, i'm fairly new to jQuery JSON stuff.  I'm trying to access the `actions > name` node in the below json output.  It looks like "actions" is an array inside of the "data" array.  The way i am getting the json results i can access the "message" portion correctly by using `fb.message` and i can access the "name" node under "from" with `fb.from.name`.  So how would i access the "name" node under the "actions" *array*?

Thanks for any help!!

CODE:

```
({ "data": [{
         "id": "1755670903_1287007912714",
         "from": {
            "name": "LifeBridge Church",
            "id": "1755670903"
         },
         "message": "Due to weather, church service tomorrow is canceled. See you next week!",
         "icon": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/23/2231777543/app_2_2231777543_9553.gif",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "\u0040lifebridgeTX on Twitter",
               "link": "http://twitter.com/lifebridgeTX?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=lifebridgeTX&utm_content=33711605665505280"
            }
         ],
         "type": "status",
         "application": {
            "name": "Twitter",
            "id": "2231777543"
         },
         "created_time": "2011-02-05T02:20:48+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-02-05T02:20:48+0000"
      },
      {
         "id": "1755670903_1281724020620",
         "from": {
            "name": "LifeBridge Church",
            "id": "1755670903"
         },
         "message": "Service tonight at 5:30... meet us at Eddins Elementary school in McKinney.  http://see.sc/8l4Cwo || Praying that God is greatly glorified!",
         "icon": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v27562/23/2231777543/app_2_2231777543_9553.gif",
         "actions": [
            {
               "name": "\u0040lifebridgeTX on Twitter",
               "link": "http://twitter.com/lifebridgeTX?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=fb&utm_campaign=lifebridgeTX&utm_content=31388610301272065"
            }
         ],
         "type": "status",
         "application": {
            "name": "Twitter",
            "id": "2231777543"
         },
         "created_time": "2011-01-29T16:30:03+0000",
         "updated_time": "2011-01-29T16:30:03+0000"
      }]
});
```

Follow-up code for additional questions:

```
$.each(json.data,function(i,fb){
    if (!fb.message) continue;
    facebookPost += '<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-theme="c">' + fb.message + ' <br /><span class="via">' + fb.created_at + ' via ' + fb.actions[0].name + '</span></li>';
    $('#facebookPosts li:first').after(facebookPost);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming when you say `fb`, that `fb = data[0]`. Then:

```
fb.actions; // Gives actions ARRAY
fb.actions[0]; // Gives first OBJECT in actions ARRAY
fb.actions[0].name; // Gives the name VALUE of the first OBJECT in actions ARRAY
```

---

From a question in the comments, to skip over items when a value doesn't exist:

```
$.each(json.data,function(i,fb){
    if (!fb.message) return true; // true to keep going, false to quit immediately
    facebookPost += '<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-theme="c">' + fb.message + ' <br /><span class="via">' + fb.created_at + ' via ' + fb.actions[0].name + '</span></li>';
    $('#facebookPosts li:first').after(facebookPost);
});
```

Comment: thanks that was just what i needed!  Also, if you happen to know...i am looping through all the objects in the data array.  How can i remove one from the loop if it returns undefined?  Or is there an easy way to do it?  Let me know if you need code example.

Comment: @Ryan, when what returns `undefined`? And by remove, do you mean skip over it (jump to the next item in the loop)?

Comment: sorry, that was a little vague.  yes, some of the objects don't have "message" and my loop create a list item like so: (this is the code inside my $.each) `fbPost += '<li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-btn-up-c" role="option" data-theme="c">' + fb.message + '<br /><span class="via">via ' + fb.actions[0].name + '</span></li>';`.  If there's no "message" i'd like the loop to skip over it.

Comment: @Ryan, added a response in my answer.

Comment: @Box9, i am now getting a syntax error: "for (...) {\n".  I took your code and just added the above `fbPost += '...';` inside of it.  Do i need to do anything with the "..." in your 'for'?

Comment: @Ryan, hehe sorry, the loop was only to show where to add the code. I meant that you should use your existing loop. The only line you need to add is the one with `continue` on it.

Comment: ok, i added the code i am using for my `$.each` (see my initial question) and i am getting an error saying "continue must be inside loop".  My code before was the same before i added that one line with the if statement.

Comment: @Ryan, right, `$.each` doesn't work quite the same as a for loop ;) Edited my answer again. By the way, are you sure you want the `.after` line *inside* the loop?

Comment: @Box9, awesome! Works perfectly now! Thanks for all the help and great information. :)

Comment: @Box9, i am having a separate issue now.  Related to the line you gave me.  jQuery isn't handling it well with it inside the $.each loop.  It is cause the loop to start over when it reaches an object that that doesn't have a "message".  It doesn't just "keep going" like i want it to.  This is causing duplicates in the final result list.

Comment: @Ryan, I'm not quite sure what you mean. The only way I see duplicates happening is due to the last line in the loop. Try moving it to **after** the loop. Also make sure you have `var facebookPost = ''` **before** the loop.

Answer (score 1):

JSON objects are just normal javascript objects, access them the same way you would normally, to get the `i`th data item's `j`th action you could use the following code. to get the first of each you could just hardcode `i=j=0`.

```
jsonResponse.data[i].actions[j].name
```

Comment: thanks...your and the other response helped fix my issue!  I choose to go with his but i'll still give you a point.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the first element in the array:

```
fb.actions[0].name
```